# ASPNET MVC 3 scaffolding with ajaxgrid or jqgrid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have an ASPNET MVC 3 project made with Entity Framework 4 (database first). I'm trying to use scaffolding to create CRUDs with jqgrid following: [MVC Custom Scaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/08/mvcscaffolding-scaffolding-custom-collections-of-files/)

But when I run something like Scaffold ControllerWithAjaxGrid StockItem it says:

> Invoke-Scaffolder : A positional parameter cannot be found that
>   accepts argument 'StockItem'. At line:1 char:9
>   + Scaffold <<<<  ControllerWithAjaxGrid StockItem
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:)
>   [Invoke-Scaffolder], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   PositionalParameterNotFound,T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.InvokeScaffolderCmdlet

Any ideas?

I'm tried to use the MVCScaffolding from nuget packages as well (Ajax Grid Scaffolder) but it doesn't show add nor edit or delete buttons).  Any ideas on that one?  I prefer to use the first one if possible.

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to copy the T4 templates, that, of course, made it work.